# AVERAGEIF with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I've seen a lot of similar questions on here, but nothing that answers what I'm specifically after.

I have a bunch of columns of contact information. Column A has the date of contact (i.e 01/11/2019). Column B has the call start time (ie. 13:42). Column D has the call end time (i.e 13:58).

I want to work out the average minutes of a call for a specific date. So to get average time spent on a call on 01/11/2019, I need a formula that searches for all instances of 01/11/2019 in column A, then for each instance get the time in column D minus the time in column B, then give me an average for all of these.

So far I have:

```
    =AVERAGEIFS(A:A,"01/11/2019",(=D:D-B:B),>0))
```

Which I assumed would give me an average if column A has 01/11/19, and the result of column D minus column B is more than 0. But it doesn't.

Please help!

Comment: Would be a lot simpler to add a column with call duration and then average that,

Comment: Not just simpler - that's the *only* way you'll get `AVERAGEIFS` to work here. :)

Comment: Yeah, but that feels like cheating. I wanted to try and do this with formula.

Comment: Is there a non-AVERAGEIFS way that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why cheating? Anyway as Rory says you can't do it like that.

Comment: You can however recreate `AVERAGEIF` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't incorporate an array of values into `AVERAGEIF`, nor `AVERAGEIFS` as they expect `Ranges`. However, you could re-create `AVERAGEIF` quite easily:

[image]

So the formula in `G2` to re-create `AVERAGEIF` could be:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A5=G1,D2:D5-B2:B5))
```

> <sub>**Note:** This formula is an array formula and needs to be
>   confirmed through
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.</sub>

Effectively this is an array (heavy on calculation, and if you wouldn't want to enter it as such, you could replace it with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5=G1)*(D2:D5-B2:B5))/COUNTIF(A2:A5,G1)
```

> <sub>**Note:** Column C is hidden in this example.</sub>

Comment: Neat (think your column refs need tweaking).

Comment: @SJR, thanks, forgot I hid column C, which isnt visible in this picture, therefor the refs are correct, but seem off :S

Answer (score 0):

Column A contains Date, Column B Start Time , column C End Time, COlumn D ( Start time - End time) , Use formula>> SUMIFS($D$2:$D$8,$A$2:$A$8,$H$3)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,H3) where H3 is the date